# When I try to open modal everything that renders with API on the background is removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a modal that shows a preview an item coming from an API but whenever I try to click one of the rendered element coming from the API modal shows up but everything removed from the background can you please help?

App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Card } from './Card';
import png from '../src/assets/folder-icon.png';
import ModalOverlay from './ModalOverlay';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [wholeData, setWholeData] = useState([]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setWholeData(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (obj) => {
    setData(obj);
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = (obj) => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const CardList = () => {
    return (
      <div className='model'>
        {data?.metadata?.map((obj) => (
          <div key={obj.objectId}>
            <div
              className='button modelCard'
              onClick={() => handleClick(obj)}
              key={obj.objectId}
            >
              <img className='card-img' src={png} alt='png' />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {data && <CardList />}
      {isOpen && (
        <ModalOverlay
          isOpen={isOpen}
          obj={data}
          wholeData={wholeData}
          closeModal={closeModal}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ModalOverlay.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ModalOverlay = ({ obj, wholeData, isOpen, closeModal }) => {
  
  return (
    <div className='modal-overlay'>
      <div className='modal-content' onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <div className='card-img'>
          <h2 className='card-title'>
            Object Name: {obj.properties.General.Name}
          </h2>
          <img
            className='object-image'
            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${wholeData.thumbnail}`}
            alt='object-image'
          />
          <button className='view-360-btn'>Go 360 View</button>
          <button onClick={closeModal}>Kapat</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalOverlay;
```

index.css

```
:root {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color-scheme: light dark;
  color: black;
  background-color: #333;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

/* CARD LIST */

.model {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(160px, 1fr));
  gap: 2.5em;
}

.modelCard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  transition: 100ms;
}

.modelCard:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1.3em);
}

/* CARD DETAILS */

.card {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-details {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0c2046;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1.2em;
}

.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.card-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.view-360-btn {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.view-360-btn:hover {
  background-color: #6ff36f;
}

.object-detail-image {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
}

.detail-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.detail-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.detail {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.detail-name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.detail-value {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* CARD PREVIEW */

/* Modal açıldığında arka planı karartmak için modal-overlay kullanıyoruz */
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0.5
  ); /* Karartma için yarı saydam bir arka plan */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: fadeIn 100ms ease-in; /* 100ms açılış animasyonu */
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.App {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 320px;
}
```

**How can I render elements that coming from the API on the background  while modal is open?**

Comment: what kind of data do you expect from that API? In your state initialization it appears like you're expecting an Array but in your modal you are using it like an object. Try to identify what kind of data do you expect first so you can use it correctly.

Comment: Why do you do this when opening the modal?: `setData(obj);`  What is the conceptual/semantic difference between "data" and "whole data" in this case?  The code is rendering what's in `data`, so if you change what's in `data` then you change what's being rendered.

Comment: Im using `wholeData` because it has just one thumbnail coming from the api. It is kind of a placeholder.  im using `setData(obj)` because modal has to show what property the object has. Im new in React but i can't find any solutions

Comment: Are you trying to use `data` to simultaneously hold *all records* and *one selected record*?  A single variable can't simultaneously hold two different values.  That has nothing to do with React.  What data is used to display all of the records in `CardList`, and what data is used to display a single record in `ModalOverlay`?  It sounds like you've simply confused yourself with your own data.  Perhaps you meant to use `wholeData` for `CardList` instead?  Perhaps your `ModalOverlay` shouldn't *overwrite* `data` but should just show one record from it?

Comment: Okay i solve the problem. All i need to do is declaring another state for modalData and this is working nothing removed in background. As you say i got very confused sometimes and it's been 2 days to solve this problem thanks a lot again.